# "Processing resource file" while building very slow

Tags: performance, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, resx

Im currently suffering with extrem slow buildprocess on my local machine.
It takes very long time when msbuild comes to "Processing resource file".
Long means, about 10 to 20 seconds per resx-file.

Those resx-files aren't big, acctually the most of them are empty and are just there because of old winform Projects.

Does anyone have any idea what i could investigate?

What i already did:

- Im running VS with administrator privileges
- All folders of VS and my Solution are excluded in Windows Defender
- im running a private, tfs server workspace
- restartet my pc :)

thanks for any advices/suggestions in advance

if more information is needed in any way, just ask :)

Comment: Please set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `detailed` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Projects and Solutions`-->`Build and Run` and then share the detailed build log with us.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT
i will do, but is there any sensitiv data in this log which should by annonymised  before posting?

Comment: Sure, you should do with that. Replace any private data with `**`.

Comment: it tells me, an error occured when adding the build log to the question and saving the edit, any ideas about that?

Comment: o man i guess i found the problem. i will edit my question and mark as solved, if possibl

Comment: Regarding roll-back: please don't add answer into question body. "Solved" question on Stackoverflow is indicated by accepted answer.

Comment: @Sinatr ok. thanks for the hint. i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was, yesterday i was investigating a bug report from a customer, with some IOException, while getting a temp file name with GetTempFileName. So i generated 65535 temporary files with GetTempFileName, because this is a documented limitation of this method (2 ^ 16 - 1 possible files), to reproduce this behaviour and simply forgot to clean up %temp% after investigation. and this msbuild behaviour was the result of a %temp% folder full of tmpXXXX.tmp files

Comment: Since you have a workaround about this issue, I suggest you could `mark your own answer`.

Comment: Yes i wanted to do that as soon as the system allows me to do that. I had to wait 2 days or something like that it said.